# Use custom data sources in RDLC reports

Tags: visual-studio, rdlc

I am doing a analysis on rdlc reports using Visual Studio. Is there a way I can provide a dynamically generated data set instead of database and tables. This way I can use the index built on entities rather than directly querying from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can pass a Dataset to [ReportDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportdatasource%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) either generated/populated dynamically or filled with data taken from your database.